# JDBC: check stored procedure return value

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a stored procedure on my postgresql database that return integer value. When i call my procedure form jdbc client using CallableStatement, when i call execute() method on CallableStatement object, it returns only a boolean. How can i read the effective return value of function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a ResultSet via:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM setoffunc()");
while (rs.next()) {
   // read results
}
rs.close();
stmt.close();
```

Or:

```
// Procedure call.
CallableStatement proc = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call refcursorfunc() }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
proc.execute();
ResultSet results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
while (results.next()) {
    // read results
}
results.close();
proc.close();
```

See the documentation for more details: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/callproc.html

Comment: No result set needed in my case, my function return only an integer. only call, after execute, proc.getInt(1) and change registerOutParameter second argument as Types.INTEGER